# mysql extract two boxes in my site

Tags: php, mysql

In my site should appear two boxes, but it appears only one

This image is from the MySQL

http://oi59.tinypic.com/n3xmwx.jpg

And this image from my website which only appears only one box instead of 2 boxes

http://oi61.tinypic.com/b3po49.jpg

that is my code that I use:

```
    <?php
  $shop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shop` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
  for($j=1; $shop = mysql_fetch_object($shop); $j++)
{

?>
<div class="buy_boxs">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr style="height:40px">


                        <div id="title-premium-boxs"><font color="#0a0e3e"><?=$shop->name?> </font></div>

                    <div class="gray-area">24-72 hour delivery</div>
                    <ul class="special" style="margin: 10px 22px 10px 40px">



<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr1?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price1?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr2?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price2?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr3?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price3?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr4?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price4?></span>
</li>
<li>
<strong><?=$shop->nr5?></strong>
<?=$shop->media?>
<span class="away">$<?=$shop->price5?></span>
</li>
</ul></a>


                <select class="selection" name="item_number" style="margin: 10px 22px 10px 25px; width: 201px">
                        <option data-price="15" value="TF1000"> <?=$shop->nr1?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price1?> </option>
                        <option data-price="20" value="TF5000"> <?=$shop->nr3?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price2?> </option>
                        <option data-price="30" value="TF10000"> <?=$shop->nr3?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price3?> </option>
                        <option data-price="75" value="TF50000"> <?=$shop->nr4?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price4?> </option>
                        <option data-price="150" value="TF100000"> <?=$shop->nr5?> <?=$shop->media?> — $<?=$shop->price5?> </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="gray-area extrapadding">
<input style="margin: -14px 23px 10px 25px; width: 188px;" type="text" placeholder="<?=$shop->placeholder?>" name="custom">
</div>


                    <div style="text-align:right">
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" id="business" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<? echo $site->site_brand;?> <? echo $pack->name;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<? echo $pack->coins;?>+ Credits">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<? echo $data->id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<? echo $pack->price;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?echo $site->site_url;?>/ipn.php">

</form>


                            </div>

                </td>

            </tr>
            <input style="width: 151px;border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; margin: 10px 22px 10px 25px; width: 201px" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="addbanner();" value="Buy Now" class="button" />
        </table>

</div>      
<?}?>

</td></tr></table>

<br clear="all">
<br>
<b><?=$lang['sp85']?></b><br>
<br>
<span style="font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;"><?=$lang['sp86']?></span>
<?
```

Thank you!

Comment: stop using mysql_*, it's depricateed.Use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Where's the rest of the loop?

Comment: what loop?   this is the code for extract from mysql

Comment: Are you trying to get data from 4 different rows, or 4 different tables?

Comment: only from table "shop"

Comment: You are going to Come back @ stackflow looking for answers as to why your db got hacked. mysql is officially deprecated. Please update your code to PDO or mysqli

Comment: @ Sam I dont know how update to PDO or mysqli :(((

Answer (score 1):

`$shop = mysql_fetch_object($shop)` is your problem. You are effectively clobbering out the result set with the first row on the first run of the loop, and then `mysql_fetch_object($shop)` just fails the other times. try

```
$shop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shop` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($shop)) {
//do stuff
echo $row->price;//...
}
```

or

ok, after looking at the code, it looks like you need to wrap some of the html in the query loop, like

```
$shop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shop` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($shop)) {
echo $row->name.",";
echo $row->media;
echo "<br />";
}
```

That should output something like

```
Facebook Likes,Likes
Facebook Followers,Followers
```

so you need to put your list generating code in that loop.

Comment: I try but not working :(

Comment: typo, should be `$row->price` not `$row['price']`

Comment: I try but is not work :(

Comment: you haven't posted enough information for anyone to answer this to your satisfaction, such as, what the table looks like, the output you expect to get, the output you are getting instead, and how you are connecting to the database

Comment: this is a working answer, so some other part of your set up is preventing this from working

Comment: everything disappears , with this code , and it gives me error :(((

Comment: I think at this point, you need to step back and read some tutorials. heres one http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your syntax in the for loop. the loop will stop execution when the second part is `true`.
In your case it is true from the start so it only executes once.

Change the for loop to

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($page)) {
// Code
}
```

Comment: I tryed but is not working

Comment: Could you show us the whole code. There are most likely more errors

Comment: `while($page = mysql_fetch_object($page)` is wrong, the result should be stored to a different variable

Comment: That is how he has it in his original code, so I tried to keep it the same. I agree, it should be stored in another variable, but this isn't wrong. And plus he us using mysql_ which is deprecated

Comment: it was wrong in the original code, and it is wrong here. the deprecation of mysql_ functions is likely not a factor in the code not working.

Comment: mysql_fetch_object acts on a result set object and returns a stdClass object. setting the result to the same variable clobbers out the result set object with the stdClass of the first row, which then prevents you from retrieving the rest of the rows, and then calls fetch_object on a stdClass variable in the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: @chiliNUT  Yes man you are right.I even had a syntax error myself.It's very hard answering coding problema on your phone

Comment: @stefanstojanovski yeah answering questions is tough on a phone for sure